# Ubuntu 19.04: Some .desktop shortcuts don't work anymore

Tags: gnome, shortcuts, .desktop, 19.04

I just updated to Ubuntu 19.04 and now some of my .desktop shortcuts don't work anymore.

For example, this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_GB]=/home/leonardo/Photoshop/AMT/Core key files/ProductIcon/ps.ico
Name[en_GB]=Photoshop
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/leonardo/Photoshop" wine64  "/home/leonardo/Photoshop/Photoshop.exe"
Name=Photoshop
Icon=/home/leonardo/Photoshop/AMT/Core key files/ProductIcon/ps.ico
```

Used to launch Photoshop perfectly, now it just opens a `gedit` window for me to edit the text file of the shortcut itself.

Did something change? What do I do?

Comment: @pomsky Nautilus is permitted to run files, other .desktop files launch fine.

Comment: @Kulfy That's needed to get the Wine app to run from the correct prefix

Comment: Is this a recent thing? They used to work on both 18.04 and 18.10. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I didn't work after removing env, I can't remove WINEPREFIX because I need it for the app itself to work. The workaround to having wineprefix in the shortcut was using env right before it, but I suppose that's now not supported anymore?

Comment: Create a new Desktop folder called... shortcuts. Use the `Files` application to move your shortcut into the shortcuts folder. Open the shortcuts folder and try your shortcut again... it should probably work. Let me know if I need to expand this into a full answer for you.

Comment: @heynnema that didn't work, I now have `/home/leonardo/Desktop/shortcuts/Photoshop.desktop` and if I click on it it still gets opened into `gedit`

Comment: Right-click on the shortcut that's in the shortcuts folder, and select Properties, then Permissions tab, check that it's marked to be an executable file. Report back.

Comment: Yeah, it is. Nautilus preferences are also set to run files on double click.

Comment: MOVE the .desktop file into the `~/.local/share/applications` folder. Hit the SUPER key and type `Photoshop`.

Comment: Oh hey that worked. That's great! Probably a better fix than what I previously had. Thank you!

Comment: Let me put together a quickie answer, and then you can accept it, ok?

Comment: Yeah of course.

Comment: The "Desktop" in 19.04 works differently than in the past... and really... only folders of stuff work there now... individual items probably won't work until they finish their programming for that.

Comment: Interesting (?) choice I guess? Doesn't seem like the best idea and also not very user friendly.

Comment: You'll note the `Desktop Icons` GNOME extension has very limited configuration options...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments...

The "Desktop" in 19.04 works differently than in the past... and really... only folders of stuff work there now... individual items probably won't work until they finish their programming for that.

MOVE the .desktop file into the `~/.local/share/applications` folder. Hit the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key and type `Photoshop`.